# How to Find the Total Number of rows MySQL Statement when using B-Tree Indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query which returns zero results set when i add the count(*) , i need to find the total number of rows affecting the search keywords, how do i do this in the MYSQL ?

```
SELECT `url` , `search_id` , `total` , `keyword`, `title`, `description`, 

( ( 1.5 * (MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) * 1000 ) + ( 1.0 * (MATCH(`description`) AGAINST (''keyword1 keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) * 1000 ) ) AS relevance , count(search_id) AS found 

FROM search_si 

WHERE 

MATCH (`keyword`,`title`,`description`,`url`) AGAINST (''keyword1','keyword'' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE ) 

-- GROUP BY `url` 
ORDER BY relevance DESC 

LIMIT 140,10
```

If i do a add a count like below it gives me zero, empty set i dont know why,

```
SELECT count(*)AS `found`, `url` , `search_id` , `total` , `keyword`, `title`, `description`, 

( ( 1.5 * (MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) * 1000 ) + ( 1.0 * (MATCH(`description`) AGAINST (''keyword1 keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) * 1000 ) ) AS relevance , count(search_id) AS found 

FROM search_si 

WHERE 

MATCH (`keyword`,`title`,`description`,`url`) AGAINST (''keyword1','keyword'' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE ) 

-- GROUP BY `url` 
ORDER BY relevance DESC 

LIMIT 140,10
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the query with the count(*) that does not work as you expect.

Comment: I just added the "count(*)AS `found`" after select, it gives me empty set, with no results found, .... i think its problems with the full text indexing

Comment: also without count query returns (6238 total, Query took 0.1183 sec)

Comment: See my answer.  You need a `group by` if you are going to use a `count(*)`.  Or else you will only get one row back.

Comment: if i add a count(`search_id`)AS `found`, and group by url, still it gives me only the 1,2,... into the found column